# Windows Server 2012 R2 GC DC Multi site issue

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller

We have quite a basic network setup in a test environment that is going to be deployed.  This is the first multi site network we have made.  We are aware that there should be more than one DC at each site, but this is not something our budget will run to, and we have some other fallback methods if needed.

Site A

- 1 x Physical Server 2012 R2
- 1 x Server 2012 R2 VM - GC DC AD DNS DHCP
- 1 x server 2012 R2 VM - File Server

Site B

- 1 x Physical Server 2012 R2
- 1 x Server 2012 R2 VM - GC DC AD DNS DHCP
- 1 x server 2012 R2 VM - File Server

Both sites are linked together, as a single domain.  Each DC is a global catalogue.  All seemed to work fine with no issues to report

The issue:
The site link failed between the sites, and the server at Site B needed to be rebooted.  On reboot it said it could not contact the domain.  It would not show any AD users or computers, and no machines at Site B could join the domain.

Only after the link was restored did everything start and work again.

On viewing the information in AD on the server at Site B replication seems fine, and changes are replicated between the servers.  However, Site B seems to be totally dependant on Site A even though it appears to have a fully active separate DC that is a GC.  This is not what we want, Site B needs to operate independently of Site A should the link fail, and then sync once the link is restored.

What have we missed?  Why could Site B's server not be rebooted correctly when the link happened to be down?

Comment: Do the computers in site B have the DC in site A as secondary DNS?

Comment: Are these set up in different sites in Active Directory Sites and Services? Did you create the appropriate subnets and point them at the right servers? They need to have themselves as primary DNS and the remote server as secondary DNS, as @GregAskew mentioned.

Comment: The computers in Site B do not have a secondary DNS set.

Comment: The servers are setup in active directory sites and servers, with a link made so that they replicate info.  I think they have the remote server as a secondary DNS.  I will check tomorrow and post back.  Thanks for the tips

Comment: What does site B DC have configured for DNS servers? Does site B DC show itself in output of nltest /dsgetdc:domain.com /server:siteBDC ? What do clients in site B show for DC in nltest /dsgetdc:domain.com?

Answer (score 0):

Site A and Site B should have each other's DNS Server IP address assigned to all the clients in both domains in order for the replication take place.

Check the DHCP server "Scope Options" whether it has DNS IP address of Site A.

Check the DHCP server "Scope Options" whether it has DNS IP address of Site B.

At last check replication in dssite.msc (Active Directory Sites and services).